# Favourite Regionerate layout

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

Just started using [Regionerate](http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/) and must say I love it!

But I'd change default layout to a bit different eg

```
Constructrors
Fields
Propierties
Public Methods
Private Methods
Events
```

Just started play with layout file, with not big success so far..

I wonder if you have your own / preferred layouts?
Maybe you can share with community? (I will if I manage that...)